# Question migrated from SO without its answers, and wrong answer count in Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, migration, answer-count

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46618/microsoft-c-language-reference) was migrated from SO. It had 5 answers at the time it was migrated. These were lost in the way.

However, the question on Meta kept "thinking" that it had 5 answers. When I added mine, the answer count was displayed as "6 Answers" - but the other 5 were nowhere to be seen.

Comment: The question wasn't properly migrated. There's no link back to the original question - which is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633330/microsoft-c-language-reference. I've flagged the question for moderator attention

Comment: There are FOUR LIGHTS!

Comment: that's very peculiar a fly marrying a bumblebee

Comment: Vanished... leaving no more trace then a tear in the rain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've made a lot of changes in the code to remove cross-db queries - this bug in question migration was a result of those changes.

A fix has been deployed.

I've reopened the [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633330/microsoft-c-language-reference), since the answers are good - I don't really think it deserves to be on Meta.  I've also deleted the failed migration here on Meta.

Comment: I've noticed some migrated questions on Super User aren't showing any user on the home page. Is this related to this problem?

Comment: @ChrisF - you are correct, sir.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a biproduct of a failed/crippled question migration.

There are 5 answers in the question that was migrated, plus the one posted while it's been on Meta (which would merely increment the denormalized answer count).

So "6 answers" makes sense if all the original answers were migrated, except they weren't.

Comment: The original question wasn't closed properly either.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I saw that. Are you able to see the edit history on that question? I only see "locked by Community" (I have less than 10k on SO).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2633330/revisions

Comment: @random: Thanks. Didn't think of that. And I am able to see that page.

Comment: I edited the question title because it seems obvious that the issue is that 5 existing answers weren't migrated, while still being counted in the answer count.