# Migrated questions show wrong number of answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-count, migrated-questions

Today I noticed a question that had been migrated from SO to Programmers.

> 1 vote 0 answers 38 views
>
> How To Deal With Terrible Design
>   Decisions [migrated]
>
> I'm a consultant at one company. There
>   is another consultant who is a year
>   older than me and has been here 3
>   months longer than I have, and a full
>   time developer. The full-time
>   developer is great.

Right now, [on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/how-to-deal-with-terrible-design-decisions), it actually has 11 votes, 12 answers, 671 views.

I haven't noticed that behavior before, although that certainly doesn't mean anything. Nowadays I'm lucky if I notice whether I've put on pants before I leave the house. That behavior--wrong counts on the site a question migrates from--like much of my own behavior, seems a little odd.

I read through many of the similar questions. I understand that SE has [reduced the number of cross-database queries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46625/question-migrated-from-so-without-its-answers-and-wrong-answer-count-in-meta). I can certainly support that idea. Is this odd behavior just a main effect of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a question is migrated, it and its answers are copied to the destination site, and the answers on the source question are deleted.

So technically, the stats are correct: there are 0 answers because all of them have been deleted or were posted on the Programmers.SE version of the question.

The side effect of this is that the question could be re-opened on the source site by a moderator and act as a separate entity, garnering its own comments, answers, views, and votes. This happens rarely, but it does happen from time to time.